# База данных хранится вне проекта на лок.сервере, как известно. Можно ли ее переместить в проект и чтобы проект при этом нормально функционировал?

Tags: база-данных, phpmyadmin

Я пользуюсь OSpanel. Где находится нужная мне база, я знаю. Хочу поместить ее в папку проекта, чтобы потом сделать git push, а на другом ПК - git pull. И чтобы проект нормально функционировал. То есть, надо где-то phpmyadmin указать (наверное...), что база теперь в другом месте лежит. Как это сделать и вообще возможно ли? Сейчас мне приходится делать экспорт базы, кидаю в облако, прихожу на работу, делаю импорт. Бред... Спасибо!

Comment: Ок, я так понял, что так можно сделать только с хостингом. Тогда там база будет в проекте, и эта же база на локальном сервере...

Comment: Раз вы говорите что то про phpmyadmin подозреваю, что ваша база это MySQL. нет, вы не можете поместить ее в проект. MySQL делает все в файлах его собственной структуры. Это файлы должны быть у него в папке (обычно /var/lib/mysql) и самое главное, эти файлы нельзя просто взять и скопировать при запущенном MySQL сервере. Как минимум сервер надо остановить. И работать эти файлы будут только на точно такой же версии MySQL. Что бы БД была в самом проекте надо рассматривать другие решения, например SQLite

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю про SQLite